# Projective plane of uniformity 4

Tags: combinatorics, hypergraphs

I was asked to construct a 4-uniform projective plane (meaning, a 4-uniform hypergraph that every two vertices belong to a single edge, and every two edges intersect in a single vertex).

I managed to construct the hypergraph below (each colored line is an edge). Now I am asked to find its $\nu^*$, which is the fractional matching number. The (not)
 fractional matching number is 1, since the maximum number of pairwise disjoint edges is 1.

Any ideas on how to find $\nu^*$? (without using MATLAB). Maybe it is related somehow to r-partite hypergraphs?

[image]

Comment: I found this useful definition: a matching in a graph is a set of edges no two of which are adjacent. The matching number is the size of a largest matching. A fractional matching is a function $f$ that assigns to each edge of a graph a number in $[0, 1]$ so that, for each vertex $v$, we have $\sum f(e) ≤ 1$ where the sum is taken over all edges incident to $v$. The fractional matching number is the supremum of $\sum_{edges} f(e)$ over all fractional matchings $f$.

Comment: You can also show that the fractional matching number is obtained by [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), where $A$ is the incident matrix of the hypergraph. With this you can calculate the number (with MATLAB for example).

Comment: So your $4$-uniform hypergraph has $\nu^*\ge\frac{13}4$ since we can assign $f(e)=\frac14$ to each edge $e.$ Is $\nu^*=\frac{13}4?$

Comment: Oh yes thank you. Because you've asked for a definition of $\nu ^*$ it got me to search for an alternative definition. Mine is using linear programming and the Euler characteristic of a hypergraph. But now I can see the that the "alternative" definition is just the one I already have, but put into words. So yes, $\nu ^*$ is $13\over 4$, and there are many fractional matching functions $f$ that give this supremum.